# How to store the output of sed command in shell script

Tags: shell

```
past_date=`date +"%Y-%m-%d" -d "-60 day"`
initial_date= sed -n "/$past_date/p" 'logfile.txt' | head -1 | sed -e 's/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/'
echo $initial_date
```

/*I am trying to store the result of sed command to initial_date variable. But nothing is stored in initial_date*/

Comment: Directly it is displaying the output ,but not able to store in variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store a command output into a variable `$var`, use the `var=$(command)` syntax:

```
initial_date=$(sed -n "/$past_date/p" 'logfile.txt' | head -1 | sed -e 's/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/')
```

Then to print the result it is always recommended to quote the variable:

```
echo "$initial_date"
```

---

#### Update

If you are looking for the first `date hour` in logfile.txt, being `date` the `$past_date`, then you can use:

```
grep -o -m1 '2013-11-14 [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]' logfile.txt
```

Given this sample file:

```
$ cat logfile.txt 
hello 2013-11-14 11:12:33
2013-11-14 11:12:33
2013-21-14 11:12:33
2013-r2:33
2013-19-14
2013-11-10 adf

$ grep -o -m1 '2013-11-14 [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]' logfile.txt 
2013-11-14 11:12:33
$ data=$(grep -o -m1 '2013-11-14 [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]' logfile.txt)
$ echo $data
2013-11-14 11:12:33
```

Comment: I have tried this answer but error is appeared like  2013-11-14: not found .

Comment: Does your command work alone? It looks like `$past_date` dir may not exist.

Comment: Directly sed -n "/$past_date/p" 'logfile.txt' | head -1 | sed -e 's/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/' command giving output, but I am not able to store in variable

Comment: If I understand your attempts properly, you are looking for the first date in `logfile.txt`. Why not doing `grep -o -m1 '2013-11-14' logfile.txt`? `grep -o` just prints the match (not the whole line) and `-m1` just matches one time and then quits.

Comment: In that logfile.txt file along with the date 2013-11-14 00:00:36
format is there, so I am using the sed to extract the value from the file line.

Comment: In that how to  find the first occurence of date which is greater than or eqaul to '2013-11-14', If that date is not found It has to give next date which is greater than 2013-11-14 date

Comment: Regarding the second comment, please if you have another question do  [Ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). It is better for clarity (and free!) : D

Answer (score 0):

initial_time=`echo $line | sed -e 's/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/'`